# Xamarin Android app dies when I attach xamarin profiler

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, adb, xamarin-profiler

I have an android app I am developing in C# with Xamarin. I have installed a trial version of VS ultimate so that I can get the xamarin profiler also.
The problem is that whenever I attach the profiler to my app, the app dies.
The debug output isn't particularly descriptive, but I see the following from the Xamarin Diagnostics output:

```
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 am force-stop com.geosolve.pavestate
[D:RunShellCommand]:      emulator-5554 setprop "debug.mono.connect" ""
```

I'm unsure why this is happening, or whether xamarin thinks it should be kulling the app for some reason. Any insights on why this could be happening?

Comment: What's your android api  version ? API 29 support is still a preview release, and has the inherent problems that preview releases usually have.

Comment: API Version is 28

Comment: Try navigating to **Debug** > **Windows** > **Exception Settings**, right-clicking **Common Language Runtime Exceptions**, and selecting **Restore Defaults**

Comment: That works! Amazing. If you post as answer, I'll accept

Comment: ok,i will post it below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the method below :

navigate to **Debug** > **Windows**  > **Exception Settings** then right-clicking **Common Language Runtime Exceptions** , and selecting **Restore Defaults**